# How do i replicate this matlab function in numpy?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

```
[A,I] = histc([0.9828    0.4662    0.5245    0.9334    0.2163],[0.0191    0.2057    0.2820    0.2851    1.0000])
```

That is the MATLAB code with the results:

```
A =

     0     1     0     4     0


I =

     4     4     4     4     2
```

What I need is I. I've tried using np.histogram but it gives me this:

```
>>> a,b = np.histogram([0.9828 ,   0.4662 ,   0.5245 ,   0.9334 ,   0.2163],[0.0191   , 0.2057   , 0.2820  ,  0.2851  ,  1.0000])
>>> a
array([0, 1, 0, 4])
>>> b
array([ 0.0191,  0.2057,  0.282 ,  0.2851,  1.    ])
```

I want to get the bins that each element in my array/matrix goes into.

Comment: Have you compared the documentation between the two? Their functionality is not the same.

Comment: See the doc here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

Comment: is there any way in numpy to get the indices that each item in my matrix/array sorts into? I need to know which bin each value in my matrix goes to.

Comment: @excaza This is not a duplicate, the author did not ask about the last element at all.  The question is about how to get the indices.

Comment: @TheBlackCat yes, that's why I deleted the comment and requested it be reopened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is `numpy.digitize`:

> Return the indices of the bins to which each value in input array belongs.

```
>>> a = np.digitize([0.9828 ,   0.4662 ,   0.5245 ,   0.9334 ,   0.2163],[0.0191   , 0.2057   , 0.2820  ,  0.2851  ,  1.0000])
>>> print(a)
[4 4 4 4 2]
```

Comment: This is valid too.  Someone marked the above linked post as being a duplicate so I decided to act on it as it seemed valid.  I've removed the duplicate though because this certainly does answer the question. Very nice.

Comment: @power2 Then please mark my answer as correct so other people can find it.

Comment: @TheBlackCat - You have to wait for 15 minutes.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer - You answered this question 12 minutes after the OP posted it.

Comment: @rayryen fair enough.

Comment: This instruction is not equivalent to matlab's `histc`. You can check that `[~, bins]=histc([1 2], [0 0.5 1])` returns `[3 0]`, whereas `digitize([1, 2], [0, 0.5, 1])` returns `[3, 3]`. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

A correct python implementation of matlab's histc is the following:

```
import numpy as np

def histc(x, binranges):
  indices = np.searchsorted(binranges, x)
  return np.mod(indices+1, len(binranges)+1)
```

Comment: This is not correct, and gives the wrong output on the example of the OP, for `histc(np.array([0.9828,    0.4662,    0.5245,    0.9334,    0.2163]),np.array([0.0191,    0.2057,    0.2820,    0.2851,
    1.0000]))`

Comment: Thanks for raising this.

Answer (score 2):

Correct implementation of MATLAB histc function in python ([source](https://github.com/jernejvivod/languages-similarity-analysis/blob/a40b9455569da2a868a4242f419da29d26d6a450/lib_naloga2/triplet_extractor.py)).

```
def histc(x, bins):
    map_to_bins = np.digitize(x, bins) # Get indices of the bins to which each value in input array belongs.
    res = np.zeros(bins.shape)
    for el in map_to_bins:
        res[el-1] += 1 # Increment appropriate bin.
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.digitize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) alone is not a complete reproduction of Matlab histc.  This works:

```
import numpy as np

def histc(X, bins):
    map_to_bins = np.digitize(X,bins)
    r = np.zeros(bins.shape)
    for i in map_to_bins:
        r[i-1] += 1
    return [r, map_to_bins]

if __name__=="__main__":
    X = np.array([0.9828, 0.4662, 0.5245, 0.9334, 0.2163])
    bins = np.array([0.0191, 0.2057, 0.2820, 0.2851, 1.0])
    [A,I] = histc(X, bins)
    print("X", X)
    print("bins", bins)
    print("A",A,"expecting", [0, 1, 0, 4, 0])
    print("I",I,"expecting", [4, 4, 4, 4, 2])
```

Comment: This instruction is not equivalent to matlab's `histc`. You can check that `[~, bins]=histc([1 2], [0 0.5 1])` returns `[3 0]`, whereas `histc(np.array([1, 2]), np.array([0, 0.5, 1]))` returns `[3, 3]`. Do you know how to solve this problem?