# Python map pixel value to it's histogram bin with cv2

Tags: python, opencv

Given an image, is there a quick way to map the pixel value to its bin?

```
img = cv2.imread('test_image.jpg')
hist_g = cv2.calcHist([img[x:x+w,y:y+h,:]], [1], None, [9], [0, 256])
```

This returns a 9x1 array with the counts of pixels that fall into 9 bins ranging from 0 - 256. I think.

What I want is `[x:x+w,y:y+h]` matrix with each entry having the bin number that the pixel gets mapped to. How can I do this?

For example, let's say I have the matrix

```
x = np.array([[154, 192],[67,115]])
```

I would like to return the matrix

```
x_histcounts = np.array([[5, 7],[3,4]])
```

based on `cv2.calcHist([img[x:x+w,y:y+h,:]], [1], None, [9], [0, 256])`

since 154 is in the 5th bin, 192 in the 7th bin, etc.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do but `9x1` is correct size for histogram. Matrix `[x:x+w,y:y+h]` is not histogram. It seems you should rather use divide every value by 9 and get integer value to get what you expect. something like `result = img[x:x+w,y:y+h,:] // 9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want map pixel to `9` bins then you can convert to grayscale and later divide by `(256/9)` using `//` to get integer numbers

```
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

result = img_gray[x:x+w,y:y+h] // (256/9)
```

---

In `calcHist` you use list of channels `[1]` so you want histogram only for one channel and it means you don't have to convert to grayscale but use `[..., ..., 1]`

```
result = img[x:x+w, y:y+h, 1] // (256/9)
```

---

**EDIT:** I tested your example data `[[154, 192], [67, 115]]` and it gives me 
`[[5, 6], [2, 4]]` instead of `[[5, 7], [3, 4]]`

```
import numpy as np

bins_number = 9

x = np.array([[154, 192], [67, 115]])
result = (x // (256/bins_number)).astype(int)

print('result:', result.tolist())
```

Using Google `"numpy histcounts matlab"` I found also [How do i replicate this matlab function in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765333/how-do-i-replicate-this-matlab-function-in-numpy) which uses `np.digitize()` to replicate `histcounts` and it also gives me `[[5, 6], [2, 4]]` instead of `[[5, 7], [3, 4]]` but I don't know if I correctly create bins ranges.

```
import numpy as np

bins_number = 9

x = np.array([[154, 192], [67, 115]])

bins = [(256/bins_number)*x for x in range(1, bins_number+1)]
result = np.digitize(x, bins)

print('result:', result.tolist())
print('bins:', bins)
```

I don't have `Matlab` so I tried to use `histc()` in [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)

```
>> [a, b] = histc([154, 192, 67, 115], [ 28.44444444,  56.88888889,  
85.33333333, 113.77777778, 142.22222222, 170.66666667, 199.11111111, 227.55555556, 256. ])

a =

   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0

b =

   5   6   2   4
```

and it also gives me `[[5, 6], [2, 4]]` instead of `[[5, 7], [3, 4]]`

---

**EDIT:** I found [numpy.histogram_bin_edges](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram_bin_edges.html?highlight=histogram#numpy.histogram_bin_edges) to generate bins ranges

```
import numpy as np

bins_number = 9

x = np.array([[154, 192], [67, 115], [0,1]])

bins = np.histogram_bin_edges(x, bins=9, range=(0, 256))

print('bins:', bins)
```

But it adds `0` as first edge so later it uses numbers `1-9` instead of `0-8` but if you use `bins[1:]` then it still use numbers `0-8`

```
import numpy as np

bins_number = 9

x = np.array([[154, 192], [67, 115]])

bins = np.histogram_bin_edges(x, bins=9, range=(0, 255))
print('bins:', bins)

print('result:', np.digitize(x, bins[1:]).tolist())
```

Comment: I clarified the question. I basically want a histcounts method that Matlab has.

Comment: my code give almost the same  result for your example data. My code round down (floor), but your data rounds up (roof) or rounds to nearest integer.

Comment: I added information about `numpy.histogram_bin_edges`